# Why isn't my count aggregate respecting my pivot columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, pivot

In the pivot query below, why is every cell in a given row identical?

I was able to fix the query by replacing `count(voo)` with `sum(voo)`, but I don't understand why `count(voo)` does not respect the `AppVersion` column.  I tried to follow [Microsoft's Complex PIVOT Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot#complex-pivot-example), which also used `Count`.

```
select pv.EventDate, [VersionAA],[VersionBB],[VersionCC],[VersionDD]
from 
(
    select ah.EventDate,ah.AppVersion,1 voo
    from AppHistory ah
    where EventDate > '2018-02-04' and reason = 1
) source
PIVOT(
    count(voo) --Fix: Replace "count(voo)" with "sum(voo)"
    For AppVersion in ([VersionAA],[VersionBB],[VersionCC],[VersionDD])
) as pv
order by EventDate
```

Example output with `count(voo)`:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| EventDate  | VersionAA | VersionBB | VersionCC | VersionDD |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2018-02-05 |      1315 |      1315 |      1315 |      1315 |
| 2018-02-06 |      1200 |      1200 |      1200 |      1200 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Corrected output with `sum(voo)`:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| EventDate  | VersionAA | VersionBB | VersionCC | VersionDD |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2018-02-05 |        12 |        18 |       300 |         3 |
| 2018-02-06 |        22 |        30 |       310 |         5 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

My intent, which was met by `sum(voo)`, was to to create a query which returned:
1) One row per day
2) One column per `AppVersion` (happily, the list of `AppVersions` is static)
3) Each cell contains a count of how many rows within `AppHistory` match the date and `AppVersion` of the column.

For reference `AppHistory` looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppHistory](
    [UserID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [AppVersion] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Reason] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EventDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [TotalActions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [created] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

**EDIT**

I tried to reproduce the problem using a small amount of data and failed.  In fact, the behavior goes away if I run `select * into #AppHistory from AppHistory where EventDate > '2018-02-04' and reason = 1` and then replace `AppHistory` with `#AppHistory` in my queries.  So now I'm even more confused.  `CheckDB` says the database is fine.

I honestly didn't think of this until now, but `AppHistory` is a bit crazy:
A) Has almost 1 billion rows
B) Has a partition scheme
C) Has a clustered columnstore index.

That said, creating a new table with the same partition scheme and columnstore index also failed to reproduce this behavior.  So, now I'm even more mystified.

**Query Plans:**
[(Bad Result)Plan using Count](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sk-awJfvz)
[(Good Result)Plan using Sum](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJ_MOJzwz)

Comment: You need to show a *small amount* of sample data that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: An excellent idea.  I edited my question with the results of trying to reproduce the problem.  I was assuming I was using `pivot` incorrectly, but now I'm suspicious that they're something weird about my data.

Comment: Try adding `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to the original query. Don't quote me on this, but that's how I solved a similar problem a colleague was having yesterday. That won't be the ultimate solution but it got him through for now.

Comment: Could you post a querplan, xml version for the query that has the wrong result? You could use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and update your question with a link.

Comment: my first doubts is that you are confuse about your own data.so according to your data,correct way of counting is sum and not count.like if your voo contain 0 and 1 in that case you do not want to count 0 or null.

Comment: @KumarHarsh: In the real data, the voo column is set to 1 voo (i.e., it's hardcoded, just like in my example). There's not really much room for confusion.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Using `MAXDOP 1` did not change my results.  I'll note that using `sum` does get me correct results, so in that sense I have a working query.  My goal in this question is more about understanding what happened than successfully being able to pull this data.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: Done.  I added both variations of the plan.  Note that column and table names are lightly anonymized via manual find/replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like a bug when producing the query plan when you have batch mode execution.

Here is a repro that shows the issue both in SQL Server 2016 (13.0.4001.0) and SQL Server 2017 (14.0.3015.40).

```
create table dbo.CS(CS bit not null, index IX_CS clustered columnstore);
create table dbo.X(C int not null);

go

insert into dbo.X(C)
select top(10000) row_number() over(order by (select null)) / 10
from sys.columns as c1, sys.columns as c2;

go

select P.[1], P.[2]
from (
     select X.C, 1 as X
     from dbo.X
     ) as T
pivot (
      count(T.X) for T.C in ([1],[2])
      ) as P
left outer join dbo.CS on 1 = 0;

select P.[1], P.[2]
from (
     select X.C, 1 as X
     from dbo.X
     ) as T
pivot (
      count(T.X) for T.C in ([1],[2])
      ) as P
left outer join dbo.CS on 1 = 0
option (querytraceon 9453);
```

Result:

```
1           2
----------- -----------
10000       10000


1           2
----------- -----------
10          10
```

Left join on dbo.CS here makes the query use batch mode and the trace flag 9453 disables batch mode.